# Returning a specific item from a list fetched using HttpClient.get()

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to Angular and following a course on Pluralsight. While trying to show details for a certain item, I can't seem to figure out how to filter the list of items I'm retrieving from a file, based on an id.

I have a service for getting the data and in there I have this method for retrieving all the items

```
private _productUrl = './api/products/products.json';
getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]>{
        return this._http.get<IProduct[]>(this._productUrl)
        .do(item => console.log(JSON.stringify(item)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
    };
```

Fairly simple, trying to wrap my head around promises, observables, etc. What I can't seen to figure out is how to retrieve the list in memory and only return the element that matches a given id.

```
getProduct(id: number): IProduct{
        this._http.get<IProduct>(this._productUrl).do(item => {if (item.productId == id) return item;});
        return null;
    }
```

I'm getting a `null` value back. So how do I go about and filter a list return from a `get` call?

Comment: You cannot synchronously return an item from an asynchronous network call. The signature you provided cannot be fulfilled. You *can* return an observable of a single item, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use the rxjs Filter Operator after flatMap Operator:

```
.flatMap(item => item)
.filter(item => item.productId === id)
```

Then the subscription will only resolve with this item.

Within your component then:

```
public selectedItem: IProduct;
public ngOnInit() {
    service.getProduct(id).subscribe(item => this.selectedItem = item);
}
```

Or using the async Pipe:
In Component:

```
public item$: Observable<IProduct>;
public ngOnInit() {
    this.item$ = service.getProduct(id);
}
```

In template:

```
<cmp product="item$ | async"></cmp>
```

Comment: On what? I can call `do` or `subscribe` on the result of the `get` call, but filter works on a list. Should I save the result of the `get` call in a local `IProduct[]` variable?

Comment: You need to filter on an emission, meaning you need the map operator in rxjs and the filter method on the array.

Comment: I'm very sorry. You are right. You have to flatmap the array first! If you call flatMap first, your array will be flatten so that every item becomes one event. See corrected example above.

Comment: The `flatMap` operator doesn't work, complains about the following ` Argument of type '(item: IProduct) => IProduct' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: IProduct, index: number) =>
ObservableInput<{}>'.` Any idea what needs to be changed?

Comment: You have to write: 
this._http.get<IProduct[]>

Comment: Solved it by using `map` function : `.map((products: IProduct[]) => products.find(p => p.productId == id))`